# Does this simple model have a name?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

For my thesis I created a simple random graph model and studied some of its properties, and I was wondering if this model has a name so I can look into it further.

The model essentially takes the Erdos-Renyi graph model and iterates it, and adds a probability $q$ at each iteration to remove a given existing edge. So more concreteley

We start with a graph $G = (V,E)$ with $E = \emptyset$.
For each iteration, we consider all pairs $x,y\in V$. If $(x,y)\not\in E$ add $(x,y)$ to $E$ with probability $p$. If $(x,y)\in E$, we remove $(x,y)$ from $E$ with probability $q$. We continue this process for $t$ iterations, and then return the graph that we have at the end. We write the resulting graph as $G(n,p,q,t)$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the Erdos-Renyi graph with different parameters: each edge will be independently in at the end with some probability $r=r(p,q,t)$ which you can in principle work out. (Indeed it has a limit as $t\to\infty$ for any nontrivial choice of $p,q$, because the state of each edge after $t$ iterations is just a two-state Markov chain.)

Comment: Haha good point. I used the same method to find the probability of an edge being present after $n$ iterations, seeing it as a two state Markov chain, but somehow I didn't conclude this was equivalent to an ER graph with that probability as parameter. If you were curious, the probability is $p^{(n)} = 1-\frac{q}{p+q} -\frac{p}{p+q}(1-p-q)^n$.